# Android Java - Read music from specific folder

Tags: java, android, directory, external, mediastore

I'm following a tutorial and have modified it to come up with this:

```
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, 
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    musiccursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, selection, null, sortOrder);
```

The above code will read all the music on my external. Is there a way for me to specify a specific a folder to read music from? I'm guessing I'll have to change the uri since that is pointing to my external, I think??

Comment: There is no direct relation between a "file folder" and what a `ContentProvider` resolves your query against. If you must, you should add a selection parameter that matches against internal URI of elements so that only elements that have correct URI are accepted by query.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do by

```
musiccursor = getContentResolver().query( uri,
                proj,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[] {"%myfolder%"},
                sortOrder);
```